# Create a QuickSight dataset from a PostgreSQL materialized view

Tags: amazon-web-services, view, materialized-views

The AWS [QuickSight Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-data-sources.html) mentions that:

> You can retrieve data from tables and materialized views in PostgreSQL instances, and from tables in all other database instances.

When creating a dataset from my PostgreSQL 9.5 database, none of my materialized views display in the list to select from.

Is the documentation incorrect? Is there somewhere else I should be selecting from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used views as my source. However I can usually see tables only from one schema. Maybe your views are in different schema?

If that is not the case, just use Query instead of Table as source for your dataset and just `select * from myview`.